# Make list of editable ggplots in powerpoint, excel, or word

Tags: r, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to create a way to make a list of plots in R that can be converted to powerpoint, excel, or word in an editable format. I can do that using the code below with the officer package, but the graph in R looks very different from the output/editable graph in powerpoint. Is there a way to fix this? I am fine with the output being in powerpoint, excel, or word. But I would like all graphs to be in one document on a separate slide/sheet/page depending on the file output type.

## create a dataset

```
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
df <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)
```

## Grouped

```
set.seed(123)
df
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(fill = condition, y = value, x = specie)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    "Position",
    values = c("black", "white", "lightgrey")
  ) +
  scale_pattern_manual(
    "Position",
    values = c("none", "stripe", "none")
  ) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(pattern = condition),
    position = "dodge",
    pattern_angle = 45,
    pattern_density = .1,
    pattern_spacing = .04,
    pattern_fill = "black",
    color = "black"
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 16, family = "sans"),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20, face = "bold")
  ) 

###put all plots in list using list()
plot_list <- list(p1,p1,p1)

dput(plot_list)

plot_list_dml <- lapply(
  plot_list, \(x)
  dml(
    ggobj = x,
    bg = "white",
    editable = TRUE
  )
)

plot_list_dml

doc <- read_pptx()
for (plot in plot_list_dml) {
  doc <- add_slide(doc, "Title and Content", "Office Theme")
  
  doc <- ph_with(doc, plot, location = ph_location_fullsize())
}

fileout <- "vectorGraphics.pptx"

print(doc, target = fileout)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there anything different aside from the relative sizes of text etc, due to the different resolution settings of your two outputs?